# Filter ListView in real time

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I want to filter a `ListView` in real time. I have an `EditText` in the `ActionBar`, and each time the user writes a character I want to update the cursor of the `ListView` filtering the information.

I have done an `AsyncTask` to perform the query but I have two questions:

1º) If the user types three characters I'm creating three `AsyncTasks` (one to search the first character, one to search the two first characters, and finally one to search the three characters). Is there a simple way to say to the `AsyncTask` to replace the previous task with the new one?

2º) How can I put a small delay to start the `AsyncTask`? So if the user types three characters without stopping, I will not create the `AsyncTask` until the end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm...Not totally sure why your using `AsyncTask` for search in real-time. Here's how I would(and have successfully) do it.

Add a `TextChangeListener` to your `Edittext`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            searchResults = myDbHelper.searchAll(s.toString());
            searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

I am searching through a sqlite database everytime a user presses a key. My `searchResults` is used to populate the `ListView`, and so after I set the get the search results, tell the list adapter that the data set changed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You would use an async task because you wouldn't want to run a long query on the UI thread.  Putting it on the UI thread would make the interface feel clunky and slow.

Comment: using this method you could set a timer to run in 200 ms that would do the query with the async task.  if another character is typed before the first timer runs you cancel the first and start a new one...

Comment: Depends on the size of your query. I'm running three queries in my searchAll method, and there is no noticeable lagging.

Comment: The AsyncTask, as John said, is to not freeze the UI with long-time queries. In fact, in the last versions of the SDK (API 11 and following I think), if you try to do a query in the UI thread, dalvik throws an exception. In any case thanks, use a TextWatcher and cancel the task if exists is a good idea :) To check if the timer was already set, do you think it's a good approach to use a syncronized boolean var?